# Need to disable deleting a marker layer in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-markers

I am working with a leaflet map that uses a custom image, draws rectangles on it with markers and tooltips at the center of each rectangle.

It includes a toolbar that sets a delete mode.  In the delete mode, the click event on the rectangle changes the rectangle color and adds it to a list to delete.  But the rectangle is not deleted.

However, the markers are deleted when clicked on.  How do I disable this deletion?

I searched the Leaflet documentation looking for an option to disable deleting the marker: I couldn't find one.

Debugging in the browser, I see that after the handler I added for the onclick event on the marker, another handler is executed in leaflet that deletes the marker.

I've pored over the configuration settings for the map, but don't see where the delete is disabled for the rectangles.